# Request URI from public directory

Tags: php, routes, frameworks, uri

Good afternoon,

I am creating my PHP framework and I came around problem while working in localhost. Problem is that I have several projects that I run from one directory through my localhost.

*For example*

I have projects such as: Example Project 1, Example Project 2, Example Project 3

To access each of them I have anchor and index page. So if I want to access Example Project 1 my URL would look like: http://localhost/Example%20Project%201/

**Problem**

Since I creating a framework I am creating routing too and request URI like this:

```
public static function uri()
    {
        return trim(
            parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'
        );
    }
```

But this returns me my full project path 'home.imphus.net%20%5bv3.0%5d/public' and I need it to return just '/' or if 'home.imphus.net%20%5bv3.0%5d/public/users' it should return 'users'.

I know this question might been asked, but I could not find suitable answer for myself.

Thanks for your help guys!

Eddie

Comment: That is strange, provided that both `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `parse_url(…, PHP_URL_PATH)` should return just the path, not the full URL. Try adding some echoing to your function that will print or log the contents of *REQUEST_URI* and then the result of *parse_url* — step by step.

Comment: Could it be problem with .htaccess and rewriting rules in there?

Comment: I think you got me wrong in my question home.imphus.net is directory not domain, full URL would look like localhost/home.imphus.net%20%5bv3.0%5d/public' but there problem is that I want to get REQUEST_URI from public directory without my project directory and public directory

Comment: If that is a static prefix (that never changes among different requests), why don't you just skip the first N characters of the string? Like `define('BASEPATH_LENGTH', strlen('home…/public'))` (at global level) and then `return substr(trim(…), BASEPATH_LENGTH);` (inside `uri` function).

Comment: It static for now, but in general I am planning to reuse framework so I want it to be dynamic

Comment: You don't have to hardcode the base path into your library source code, — it may be defined elsewhere in an included file or and environment variable, just like any other configuration usually occurs. Otherwise, how your code is supposed to guess that string by itself?

Comment: Cheers! I am gonna use that for now!